# List of important business and economic news events between 1850 and 1930?

Tags: stock-market, economic-history

I'm collecting data on important business and economic news dates in the late 19th to early 20th century. The only list I found is this: https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/news-wires-white-papers-and-books/1878-1899-business-and-economy-chronology. I'm trying to identify dates in which there were important news for the U.S. stock market.

Does anybody know of any other sources? Perhaps another encyclopedia, a news article, or an academic paper?

Comment: The US was somewhat of an emerging market at that time; the European economies were more developed. Pretty hard to define what news is important in that context, as well as attempting to list the events. On the economics side, not a great deal of data published during most of that era, so defining events is tricky as well. You would also need to look at the composition of the stock market at each point in time to see what counts as important.